# C# Web API POST parameter FromBody is always null

Tags: c#, json, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, frombodyattribute

I've been scouring the web for hours and tried many different solutions also described here on StackOverflow. I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of the answers or comments have worked for me.

The problem: I have a .NET Web API that has a Post-method with some parameters.
One of the parameters is a complex object that is supposed to be read from the body (that is JSON). However, this **object is always null**.

This is my code:

```
// POST api/worksheets/post_event/true/false
        [Route("post_event/{newWorksheet}/{eindEvent}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public Event Post(bool newWorksheet, bool eindEvent, [FromBody] Event eventData)
        {
            return eventData;
        }
```

To be clear: eventData is the object that's always null. The boolean values are read correctly.

The full request body is:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/worksheets/post_event/true/false
Content-Type: application/json
{"Persnr":1011875, "WorksheetId":null, "Projectnr":81445, "Uursoort":8678, "Tijd":{"09-08-2016 9:25"}}
```

And for reference, this is the Event-class:

```
public class Event
    {
        public long Persnr { get; set; }
        public int WorksheetId { get; set; }
        public int Projectnr { get; set; }
        public int Uursoort { get; set; }
        public DateTime Tijd { get; set; }
    }
```

Some of the things I've already tried:

- Change JSON to different formats (only values, "Event": {} surrounding the actual object, an = in front of the JSON).
- Test with just the Event parameter (removing the others as well as in the route)
- Add a default ctor to Event.
- Remove the [FromBody] tag. If I do this, the Event-object is not null, but all the properties are. Properties can be filled through the URI, but that is not the desired behavior.

According to all solutions and documentation I have read, it should simply work the way I have it displayed above.
What am I missing?

Comment: worksheetId should be an int not a nullable int right?

Comment: I believe the Jsonserializer will translate that to 0 automatically, doesn't it?

Comment: Most likely,  make sure your event is bound to the right namespace you could be tied to a different class in your controller

Comment: That's not the case, Johny, but thanks!

Comment: It was in fact a combination of your answer about the int (shouldn't pass null but 0) and the datetime should be without brackets/braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json object is invalid. My suggestion is to always run json object written manually through a json parser like this: http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
"Tijd":{"09-08-2016 9:25"}
```

should instead be

```
"Tijd":["09-08-2016 9:25"]
```

Comment: It worked without the brackets or braces (so just `"09-08-2016 9:25"`). Thanks also for your link to the Parser. It helped :)
The thing was, I had 2 mistakes. The date, but also the int value. It mustn't be null, but 0. It should have just parsed the correct values, at least then I could have seen the problem is with those specific fields.

Comment: @DevvoX I assumed that you were trying to make an array of times since you had added the braces ;)

Answer (score 1):

**This usually happens when your object can't be deserialized from JSON request.**

The best practice would be to **make sure that all the request properties can accept `null` values** (make value types properties are [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)). And then you can validate that all needed request properties are provided, or return [400 error](https://httpstatuses.com/400) if not. This way you at least will be able to understand what request property causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The right JSON for this type should be just

```
{"Persnr":1011875, "WorksheetId":null, "Projectnr":81445, "Uursoort":8678, "Tijd":"09-08-2016 9:25"}
```

No curly braces for Tijd, because Tijd is plain DateTime property that can be inferred from string, representing DateTime

Comment: Well I assume the purpose of the curly braces was to have an array of several time objects. So instead of removing the braces he should use brackets.

Comment: It was in fact a combination of your answer about the date (shouldn't pass with braces/brackets) and the int value should be 0, not null.